# Image Picker - save uri with Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I have a little problem with saving my uri of a picture I have chosen in my react native app.

**The following code sample is crucial:**

```
const ProfileScreen = props =>{
    const [pickedImage, setPickedImage] = useState(null);

    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false); //State for visible Modal
    const [userBio, setUserBio] = useState('Useless Placeholder'); //State for users text in the bio

    const verifyPermissions = async () => { //ask for permissions on iOS and Android
        const result = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        if (result.status !== 'granted'){
            Alert.alert("Insufficient permissions!", "You need to grant galery permissions to customise your profile picture!", [{text: "Got it."}]);
            return false;
        };
        return true;
    };

    const takeImageHandler = async () => { //function that opens up the camera
        const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();
        if (!hasPermission){
            return;
        }
        const image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            quality: 0.5,
            aspect: [16,16]
        });
        setPickedImage(image.uri);
        console.log("Data raw is: " + image.uri);
        console.log("Data from hook is: " + pickedImage);
    };

    if(userBio.length == 0 && modalVisible == false){
        setUserBio("Useless Placeholder");
    };
```

As you can see, I have 2 console logs to check my outcome. I want to save the image.uri to my hook I declared at the top of my ProfileScreen. The problem is what I get as an output in my console:

> Data raw is:
> file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540kubaguette%252FPigeonBuddy/ImagePicker/30953995-840b-451e-a505-6082df16b9e3.jpg
> Data from hook is: null

Why is `setPickedImage(image.uri)` not working here? **Why can I `console.log` my uri of the chosen picture but not save this uri to my hook and retrieve it?**

Comment: takeImageHandler is an async function which is keeping the value of pickedImage in the closure. After set console it in the render instead of takeImageHandler method and verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setPickedImage` as any method which updates the state is [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) by nature.

If this is the only issue, you can track the changes with `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(pickedImage);
}, [pickedImage]);
```

You can see the difference here: https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-async-rnzox?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I really got to understand async and useEffect a little bit better aswell as using hooks.